# Having trouble adding to a List that exists

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a user script that contains a List inventory. Then I use a public static User user to access a single user's information throughout the game.

The problem is at some point I'm losing the link to that inventory.
In the awake function if I call Debug.Log(User.user.inventory.Count), it prints 0.
however if i try and access this inventory at any future time I get a Null Reference error as if it doesn't exist and can't add to it.

If I make the size of the list in the inspector to 1, then it somehow exists and I can add things to it forever, however then I have a dead spot at index 0.

```
 private void AddItemToInventory(ItemObject item, Image uiSprite)
    {
        User.user.inventory.Add(item);
        uiSprite.sprite = GenerateOrbRaritySprite(RaritySprites.raritySprites, item.rarity);
        uiSprite.enabled = true;
    }
```

It is failing on the inventory lookup, even though I can see it in the inspector fine.

My User has the following Awake() function so that it stays between scenes:

```
void Awake()
{
    if(user == null)
    {
        user = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else if (user != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: is your object really accessed `User.user.`?

Comment: Its just a static user instance:
In the User.cs I have public List<ItemObject> inventory;

And then my instance of User is called user. public static User user;

Comment: Generally you would call that `User.Instance`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with just one User.

```
private void AddItemToInventory(ItemObject item, Image uiSprite)
{
    user.inventory.add(item);
    uiSprite.sprite = GenerateOrbRaritySprite(RaritySprites.raritySprites, item.rarity);
    uiSprite.enabled = true;
}
```

And since this method doesn't have access to the user the user will need passed in as a parameter.

```
private void AddItemToInventory(User user, ItemObject item, Image uiSprite)
{
    user.inventory.add(item);
    uiSprite.sprite = GenerateOrbRaritySprite(RaritySprites.raritySprites, item.rarity);
    uiSprite.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Hey bruglesco thanks for the reply! I get an error that user doesn't exist in this context since I'm adding to the inventory in a different script than the static user instance is created.

Comment: @Holden You need to access the user before you can update it with a new inventory. Does passing the user as an argument work?

Comment: It did not work however it let me to the answer! There was a place where I was overwriting my inventory with a blank one. Thank you for the direction!